# How to get the values of a button dynamically

Tags: community, apex

My main motto is to get the respective button name,status with toggle property(if i clicked the same 2nd time,the seat name must be removed from the list and status value must be changed) from the list of buttons

VF Page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!repeatSeats}" var="rseats" >
<apex:commandButton id="LseatBtn"  reRender="repeatop,repeatop1,LseatBtn" action="{!rseatsAction}" image="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!seatUrl}">
</apex:commandButton>   
</apex:repeat>
```

Apex Class:

```
public List<withLoopMethod> getRepeatSeats()
{
    List<withLoopMethod> str11 = new List<withLoopMethod>();
    for(integer i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        str11.add(new withLoopMethod('seat'+i,status));
    }
    return str11;
}


Class withLoopMethod
{
       String str;Boolean status;
       withLoopMethod(String str,Boolean status)
       {
           this.str = str;
           this.status = status;
       }
}
```

Can u please suggest the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a param tag to your commandButton:

```
    <apex:commandButton value="Let's go" action="{!rseatsAction}">
        <apex:param name="nickName"
            value="{!rseats.aStringVariable}"
            assignTo="{!rseats.myVariable}"/>
    </apex:commandButton>
```

Source: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/

Comment: when i use param function , it is giving me an VF error as follows: A String, Number, or Boolean is required for attribute &#39;value&#39; in &lt;apex:param&gt;. Any Idea?

Comment: is myVariable a public variable in your controller?

Comment: Yes, it is a public variable

Comment: You should replace "rseats" with a string value.

Comment: It won't work.Since, i created the buttons using List function it will pop up a run time vf error when i click on a individual button.

Comment: you can add a variable to your list objects... You are not allowed to assign a variable twice...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you following workaround:

1) Instead of command button use Action Function
2) Create a simple HTML button and write onClick event on that
3) In onclink pass 'this' to JavaScript function
4) In your JavaScript function access all properties of button (name, id etc.)
5) Pass JavaScript variable to to action function

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456399/how-to-use-this-reference-of-the-element-calling-the-function